.NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid Bluetooth
I am trying to make a simple chat app using Bluetooth in .NET MAIU Blazor Hybrid, which should work for android, if possible also for windows.
Is there any one to help me with this?
I try a lot of ways in past few days using ChatGPT guide in Plugin.Ble and Gethub projects, but actually I did not get the expected result

Hi Ihsan. Make sure to edit your question and include:

Which approaches have you tried?
Add sample code showing the exact places where you have issuies.
Try to figure out whats the first issue blocking you and post that here so we can help you move forward one step at a time.
You should keep posting different questions for each different issue you need to resolve. As a rule of thumb, just asking one general questions about building a full system is not the best approach here.

